# How to keep original URL in addressbar after RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-redirect

This is my .htaccess file.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^index.html             /? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^listen/$               /console [R=301,L]


# 301 Redirect all requests that don't contain a dot or trailing slash to
# include a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.
RewriteRule ^(.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

# Rewrites urls in the form of /parent/child/
# but only rewrites if the requested URL is not a file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

The rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^listen/$               /console [R=301,L]
```

Redirects the url `www.mydomain.co.uk/listen` to `www.mydomain.co.uk/console`

This redirect works fine, but I want the visable url in the address bar to read...

`www.mydomain.co.uk/listen`

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Remove `R=301` flag to make it `RewriteRule ^listen/$ /console [L]`

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but it is still not working...

Comment: Clear your browser cache.

Comment: Yeah, I did several times and tried in a different browser

Comment: Is it because that othe rewrite rule ( RewriteRule ^(.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L] ) appears afterwards ? I tried changing the order, but the redirect broke completly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# 301 Redirect all requests that don't contain a dot or trailing slash to
# include a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.
RewriteRule ^(.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ /? [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^listen/$ /console/ [NC,L]

# Rewrites urls in the form of /parent/child/
# but only rewrites if the requested URL is not a file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Test it after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Thankyou. Appreciate your help. That worked.However, one thing I (naively) didn't anticipate happening, is that all the relative links to css / js etc are now broken !

Comment: That is due to use of relative links. You can add this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`