# park a domain without redirecting in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirect

i have a wordpress website with this name mydomain.ir 
i parked  mydomain.com to this website. but when i type mydomain.com it redirect to mydomain.ir
i want to address stay on mydomain.com .
i try some plugins but didnt work properly.
my host service told that this is a worpress error and you should change your codes.
i tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32114564/how-to-keep-original-url-in-addressbar-after-rewriterule) but didnt work too
what can i do to do this?
thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that you have the correct url at wordpress settings. Check Settings->General and make sure that site and home urls ar the one you want.

Next, check if there is any kind of redirection at .htaccess file.

Then, check at your cpanel if you have added any redirection there.

Finally, make a search at your wordpress database for your unwanted domain name. Make sure to change all old urls to the new one. Try this plugin for that: https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/

Update:

Alternatively, you may want to mask your domain. This should be done through your domain name registrar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer . But i don't want to Move to new Address. i Just want to when anybody type mydomain.com it shows mydomain.ir content but with .com url . if i move to new domain my ranking and seo will gone.

Comment: I updated the answer. Check if this is useful for you.

Comment: i want to advertise my website on google adwords. but they dont support ".ir" domains. so i have to park ".com" domain on my site . but when i park ".com" in my cpanel, it redirects ti ".ir" and google dont accepts redirect links. if i can park .com (not redirect to .ir) my problem will solve.